# polymer submenus and items from json

Tags: json, polymer

I'm trying to generate Polymer submenus and items from json. The code is just nested submenu & item templates:

```
<polymer-element name="years-submenu" noscript>
  <template>
    <core-ajax auto url="../json/years and offices.json" response="{{items}}" handleAs="json"></core-ajax>
    <template repeat="{{item in items}}">
      <core-submenu icon="visibility" label="{{item.year}}">
          <template repeat="{{office in item.offices}}">
            <core-item id="{{item.year}} {{office}}" label="{{item.year}} {{office}}"></core-item>
          </template>
      </core-submenu>
    </template>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

The json data could be structured any old way, but currently it looks like this:

```
[
  {
        "offices": [
            "Mayor",
            "Council At-Large"
        ],
        "year": "2014"
    },
    {
        "offices": [
            "Council Chairman",
            "Council At-Large",
            "Council Ward 2",
            "Council Ward 4"
        ],
        "year": "2012"
    }
]
```

This renders the years, but not the office names.  Oddly, if I inspect the elements in chrome, I can see that it is inserting the {{item.year}} and {{office}} for the id but not for the label. I've tried various ways of explicitly binding, but to no avail; of course, I may have been trying the wrong ways. Any ideas on how to make this work would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It's working for me: http://jsbin.com/fejewo/1/edit. Are you importing all of the elements you're using?

Comment: @ebidel I am importing them, though undoubtedly I'm doing something else wrong. You know, in looking at your jsbin code, it looks like the labels for the submenus aren't showing. In my code, the reverse is the problem -- the items aren't showing.  Can you explain why the submenu labels don't show in your jsbin code?  That might help me understand.

Comment: @ebidel Or, at least I think I am.  I'm importing core-submenu from the core-submenu.html inside the core-menu folder of my bower_components. Is that correct? (I did try to bower install core-submenu separately, but was unable to do so.)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that if I put wrap my submenu code inside  within my custom element (rather than calling the submenu from the main page that wraps my custom element inside , it works.

So, calling the element posted in the question as follows does not work:

```
<core-menu selected="{{selected}}" valueattr="id" theme="core-light-theme">
  <years-submenu></years-submenu>
</core-menu>
```

But the following called from the main page does work:

```
<polymer-element name="years-menu" noscript>
  <template>
    <core-menu selected="{{selected}}" valueattr="id" theme="core-light-theme">
      <core-ajax auto url="../json/years and offices.json" response="{{items}}" handleAs="json"></core-ajax>
      <template repeat="{{item in items}}">
        <core-submenu icon="visibility" label="{{item.year}}">
          <template repeat="{{office in item.offices}}">
            <core-item id="{{item.year}} {{office}}" label="{{item.year}} {{office}}"></core-item>
          </template>
        </core-submenu>
      </template>
    </core-menu>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

I don't fully understand why, but problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I created a polymer element to create a menu from JSON. It has some other cool features, and I am going to continue to enhance it.

It doesnt exactly fit your question but check it out.

Create a github issue/pull request if you have any issues/ideas

https://github.com/sup3rb0wlz/nb-menu